# Why is my connected App not visible in the App Launcher?

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, app-launcher

When viewing the connected app in `App Manager` the `Visible in Lightning Experience` checkbox is not checked. If I'm using Salesforce to SSO into another app, how can I surface this connected app in the App Launcher?

Comment: Does it have a start url and your profile added in Profiles?

Comment: Yes @manjit5190, it does.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320038&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, we can't have connected app as part of App Launcher. Instead as a workaround, you may have a web-link tab, and that tab you can use in the particular Application.

So, if you want to see the connected app, you can click the tab which will redirect to the connected app page.

PS - It depends on the permission you're having to see the connected app.